# Do Nietzsche's values justify some actions?

Tags: nietzsche, values

Do Nietzsche's values *justify* some *actions*? I'm asking because if so then my entirely trivial, or at least unfocused, appropriation of his ideas can be easily made more elegant, or at least more trivial still.

I am often at a loss as to why someone could think a particular justification is a good one, and I would like to be able to point out that, while some things are good justifications, others are not, even to nihilists like Nietzsche.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. If there is any book or passage by Nietzsche that is particularly relevant to the question this would help provide context so an answer can be more relevant to you.

Comment: a) Nietzsche's not a nihilist, he fights against nihilism b) I'm having trouble understanding the force of the question; what kind of values are you thinking of, that don't justify actions?

Comment: Yes. Ensuring one maintains a healthy contempt for base human stupidity, and avoiding any condesention with idiits

Comment: Is a worthwhile course of action for someone like Nietzsche. Even if it manifests itself simply as tutting at news broadcasts occasionally.